# how to get current location as i slide the MapView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, mkannotation

I am using CLLocationManager to retrieve current location in my app and display using MapView, i want to slide the map so that the current location should also change to the new location where the map slides and it should annotate to the new location, how to do it? Please give your suggestions with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't mean "the current" since that means where the phone actually is, unless you want to transport the phone to another place when using this app which would be quite a feat. So, how about drawing a layer over the top of your map that keeps a pin drawn at the centre so it looks as if the pin is moving over the map, but really the map is moving under the pin.